# Sorting number in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, filter, innerhtml

With the help of [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp), I tried to create a filter for sorting **Marks** from ascending to descending and vice versa.

But it is not sorting. And it seems there's an error somewhere at: `getElementsByTagName("SPAN").innerHTML` but I am not able to solve it.

**Also**, After sorting the first column (Sr.) should not change!

```js
function sortTable() {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc";
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[2];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[2];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (Number(x.getElementsByTagName("SPAN").innerHTML) > Number(y.getElementsByTagName("SPAN").innerHTML)) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (Number(y.getElementsByTagName("SPAN").innerHTML) > Number(x.getElementsByTagName("SPAN").innerHTML)) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount++;
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="sortTable()">Sort</button></p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Sr</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Marks</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="font-elephant">1</td>
    <td class="font-elephant">John</td>
    <td class="font-elephant"><span>438</span> Passed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="font-elephant">2</td>
    <td class="font-elephant">Kevin</td>
    <td class="font-elephant"><span>238</span> Failed</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="font-elephant">3</td>
    <td class="font-elephant">Lux</td>
    <td class="font-elephant"><span>568</span> Passed</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="font-elephant">4</td>
    <td class="font-elephant">Bro</td>
    <td class="font-elephant"><span>538</span> Passed</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

But it is not sorting. And it seems there's an error somewhere at: `getElementsByTagName("SPAN").innerHTML` but I am not able to solve it.

**Also**, After sorting the first column (Sr.) should not change!

Comment: To answer your original question, `getElementsByTagName('SPAN').innerHTML` will never get you what you want, as `getElementsByTagName()` returns an NodeList (like an Array), rather than a single node. Instead, you need to either `getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[0].innerHTML` to specify the first el in that array, or `querySelector('SPAN').innerHTML` to use a single-node query selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution: first extract the value of each`span` element then sort them with Array.prototype.sort and then reinsert them to your DOM.

```js
let ORDERED = false;

function sortTable() {
  // Get DOM nodes
  const nodes = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tr");
  // Create JS array
  const arr = Array.from(nodes);
  // Remove first row (title)
  arr.splice(0, 1);
  // Create array of objects {node: DOMNode, value: number}
  // Then sort with Array.prototype.sort which takes a callback argument
  let sorted = arr.map(node => ({
      node,
      value: parseInt(node.querySelectorAll(".font-elephant")[0].innerHTML)
    }))
    .sort((a, b) => (a.value > b.value) ? 1 : -1);
  if(ORDERED) {
      sorted = sorted.reverse();
      ORDERED = false;
  }
  else ORDERED = true;
  // Get table node to append elements to
  const table = document.querySelector("#myTable");
  sorted.forEach(({
    node
  }) => table.appendChild(node));
}

document.querySelector("#sortButton").addEventListener("click", sortTable);
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<p><button id="sortButton">Sort</button></p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Sr</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Marks</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="font-elephant">1</td>
    <td class="font-elephant">John</td>
    <td class="font-elephant"><span>438</span> Passed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="font-elephant">2</td>
    <td class="font-elephant">Kevin</td>
    <td class="font-elephant"><span>238</span> Failed</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="font-elephant">3</td>
    <td class="font-elephant">Lux</td>
    <td class="font-elephant"><span>568</span> Passed</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="font-elephant">4</td>
    <td class="font-elephant">Bro</td>
    <td class="font-elephant"><span>538</span> Passed</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: It only does: `ascending to descending` and not vice versa.

Comment: @tusa, that's kind of a nitpicking point. That would simply be a matter of setting an `order` variable and, depending on the order, reversing the logic in the `sort` function.

Comment: I made an edit with a global boolean and array.prototype.reverse to support descending. It is not the cleanest solution though

Comment: You could do something similar, for example, save a data flag on the `th` indicating sort order - that would not only allow for reverse sorting, but by sorting by, for example, `Name`. But my point was, and is, that this does address exactly the question asked. I was working on a similar solution, but you beat me to it. ;)

Comment: After sorting the first column (Sr.) should not change! How to implement that?

Comment: Sure. toward the end there's a `sorted.forEach...` - inside there, do this: `sorted.forEach(({node}, index) =>{node.querySelector("td").innerText=(index+1); table.appendChild(node) });` -- see that working here: https://repl.it/@TobiasParent/SortTheTableData

Comment: @Snowmonkey I asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57341205/changing-column-on-searching-in-html-table) for *first column (Sr.) should not change*. Please have a look there!

Comment: Sort doesn't work correctly with numbers, example 1 11...
See for yourself:
https://jsfiddle.net/meggis/gfme6r71/1/

Comment: @Meggis the issue is not with the sort method, but with the selector, it selects the last column instead of the first one. I updated my solution.

Answer (score 1):

The script below sorts Marks from ascending to descending and vice versa.

```js
function sortTable() {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc";
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[2];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[2];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (Number(x.querySelector("span").innerHTML) > Number(y.querySelector("span").innerHTML)) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (Number(y.querySelector("span").innerHTML) > Number(x.querySelector("span").innerHTML)) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount++;
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="sortTable()">Sort</button></p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Sr</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Marks</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="font-elephant">1</td>
    <td class="font-elephant">John</td>
    <td class="font-elephant"><span>438</span> Passed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="font-elephant">2</td>
    <td class="font-elephant">Kevin</td>
    <td class="font-elephant"><span>238</span> Failed</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="font-elephant">3</td>
    <td class="font-elephant">Lux</td>
    <td class="font-elephant"><span>568</span> Passed</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="font-elephant">4</td>
    <td class="font-elephant">Bro</td>
    <td class="font-elephant"><span>538</span> Passed</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```