# Changing column on searching in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-filter

Created a custom search in the table using javascript. Working as expected!

Can (**Sr.**) always be 1,2,3,etc?

Meaning, In the below script, if I search "vin", it will show only that row having character "vin" in the name. So in below, there is only one. Now it's showing Sr number as ***2***, but as there is only 1, it should show 1.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table_search").on("keyup", function() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("table_search");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("table_body");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
      if (td) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.form-control {
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input class="form-control" id="table_search" type="text" placeholder="Search..."></p>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Marks</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table_body">
    <tr>
      <td class="font-elephant">1</td>
      <td class="font-elephant">John</td>
      <td class="font-elephant"><span>438</span> Passed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="font-elephant">2</td>
      <td class="font-elephant">Kevin</td>
      <td class="font-elephant"><span>238</span> Failed</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="font-elephant">3</td>
      <td class="font-elephant">Lux</td>
      <td class="font-elephant"><span>568</span> Passed</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="font-elephant">4</td>
      <td class="font-elephant">Bro</td>
      <td class="font-elephant"><span>538</span> Passed</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If the user input number, you want to search in Sr column and input text, search in Name column, right?

Answer (score 0):

Just add more Sr column when searching. 
Try following this. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table_search").on("keyup", function() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, tdSr, tdName, i, txtSrValue, txtNameValue;
    input = document.getElementById("table_search");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("table_body");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      tdSr = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];   
      tdName = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
      if (tdSr) {
        txtSrValue = tdSr.textContent || tdSr.innerText;
        txtNameValue = tdName.textContent || tdName.innerText;
        if (txtNameValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1
        || txtSrValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7vnchukx/

Comment: No, I don't want to sort as per Sr. search. I need Sr. always be 1,2,3.....

Comment: @tusa: Sorry my friend. I don't understand your mean. Can you clarify this "Sr. always be 1,2,3? Or you can describe your scenario, input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually wanted to **show index number of the search result**, add one 'th' element for Serial Number and a 'td' element in each 'tr' element.

And then change the .innerHTML of the Serial Number, accordingly.

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```html
<style>
.form-control {
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}
</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input class="form-control" id="table_search" type="text" placeholder="Search..."></p>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Serial</th>
      <th>Student ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Marks</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table_body">
    <tr>
   <td></td>
      <td class="font-elephant">1</td>
      <td class="font-elephant">John</td>
      <td class="font-elephant"><span>438</span> Passed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td></td>
      <td class="font-elephant">2</td>
      <td class="font-elephant">Kevin</td>
      <td class="font-elephant"><span>238</span> Failed</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
   <td></td>
      <td class="font-elephant">3</td>
      <td class="font-elephant">Lux</td>
      <td class="font-elephant"><span>568</span> Passed</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
   <td></td>
      <td class="font-elephant">4</td>
      <td class="font-elephant">Bro</td>
      <td class="font-elephant"><span>538</span> Passed</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table_search").on("keyup", function() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("table_search");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("table_body");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0, sr = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
      if (td) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
    sn = td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    sn.innerHTML = sr++;
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  });
  
  $('#table_search').keyup();
});
</script>
```